# Trying to rent car in USA for more than 30 days

Tags: usa, driving, car-rentals, road-trips

We want to rent a car in Las Vegas in February, travel across California and Arizona, then return it to Las Vegas approximately 35 days later. When I check car rentals it shows that at the 30 day mark we have to return to Vegas to have it checked then rent again. This doesn't work for us since we won't be anywhere near Las Vegas at the 30 day mark.

Does anyone know a company that lets you rent for 35 days, without having to go back to rental location at the thirty day mark?

Comment: Can't you change a bit your itinerary? There are things around Las Vegas worth spending few days (maybe not 5 though).

Comment: Maybe call them up and ask if you can have it checked at another agency? Or do two one-way rentals. Again, call and ask if you could get the one way fees omitted/reduced by re-renting the same car.

Comment: LV is right between AZ and California. I would go do AZ and Grand Canyon or whatever, go back to LV, get the car checked or return it and get a new rental, then go do California. Or the other way.

Comment: Budgets, Dollar, Enterprise, and Hertz all offer rentals for more than 30 days. For most companies, they're technically leases and that makes them complicated. I'd strongly suggest taking the advice of others and doing two one-way rentals.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience there are no additional one-way rental fees between California and Nevada for most companies, Arizona might be different. You could simply rent two cars one-way: Las Vegas to X and X to Las Vegas.

Make sure not to switch at an Airport agency, they tend to be more expensive. ([From Johns-305 comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85435/trying-to-rent-car-in-usa-for-more-than-30-days/85436?noredirect=1#comment200211_85436))

Comment: I have no hard facts at hand, but I assume that the rates for 15+20 or 18+17days respectively is not going to be sufficiently different than the one for 30 days.

Comment: Bonus for this approach is the option to get a convertible or some other "fun" car for a couple of days. If that's of any interest. I once had a convertible some 10 years back for a weekend (San Francisco, Santa Cruz, Yosemite, Lake Tahoe and back) and it was quite fun (and a lot of driving).

Comment: pintxo is correct.  The rate for splits somewhere in the middle will be insignificant.  OP will likely save more by turning the car at a non-airport location.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Rates are frequently VERY different for one-way rentals, including NV->CA.  This is especially true for US residents, although at certain times of the year it is also true for non-US residents.

Answer (score 0):

I rent a car 5 years ago from Alamo for 60 Days (pick-up and return at San Francisco, CA). We did this through a travel agency at home (in Europe). Travel agencies sometimes have the option to do more complex bookings. We got two vouchers from them, 30 days each I think. We did not had to return the car after the first voucher expired.

But to know this for sure at pick-up time, we had to talk to the manager of the Alamo agency, regular staff had no idea how to handle this. And when we returned the car, they charged the credit card for the second period and we had to write them to give us our money back...